# How Syncfusion.blazor could work using refrences?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly, syncfusion

[image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuMZY.png)

i have installed syncfusion.blazor component from nuget package and its updated in references, but when I am trying to use it its showing refrence couldnot be found, what could be the possible reason and solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've tested, it looks like you created a blazor webassembly app based on .Net Core 3.1(out of support).

But if you check the syncfusion.blazer 20.4.0.50 nuget package, you can find that it is based on .Net 6.0 or .Net 7.0.

At least try to use .Net 6.0, .Net Core 3.1 is out of support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given screenshot, you have registered the Syncfusion Blazor service in the server project (DMSBlazor.Server). To resolve this issue, you should register it in the client project's ~/Program.cs file. For more details, refer to [this link](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/getting-started/blazor-core-hosted#register-syncfusion-blazor-service).